# Espresso Test is running twice

Tags: android, junit4, android-espresso, android-instrumentation

In order to do code coverage and instrumentation tests I have used a Junit Test Suite for execution order, as there are some dependent classes. The issue is my test is getting executed in order as per junit test suit **BUT** test is getting executed **twice** ... **one as per Junit test suite** and **one in random order**. **I need to do only one iteration which is defined in Junit test suite.**

```
@Suite.SuiteClasses({
        test1.class,
        test2.class,
        test4.class,
        test3.class,
        test8.class,
        test7.class

})
```

Tried with below two configuration, still test is running twiee i.e 1 as per Test Suite and one in random order

```
testInstrumentationRunner 'android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner'
```

When i try to execute with below configuration, test suit is empty is displayed

```
testInstrumentationRunner 'com.xx.xxx.modules.runner.JunitTestSuite'
```

I have used below annotations in my test class files ... please note i do not want execution as per method order in class. i have already used `@FixMethodOrder(MethodSorters.NAME_ASCENDING)`  for the same. I need to do same with class .. i.e i need to execute the test with the help of class order

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to answer based on several assumptions, please correct those in the original question if I get anything incorrect.

First, a caveat that it's best practice to write tests that don't depend upon run order in order to succeed, but if that's not an option, the solution below may work for you.

It sounds like what is happening is that the test is running as part of the Suite and on its own.  You can get around this in several ways, but assuming all of your test classes are in your Suite class, the easiest is to only run the Suite Class in your test runner.  If you are running the tests from the gradle command line, you can do this by passing an argument like this (I assume that your Test Suite class is named 'com.xx.xxx.modules.runner.JunitTestSuite'):

```
-Pandroid.testInstrumentationRunnerArguments.class=com.xx.xxx.modules.runner.JunitTestSuite
```

If you are not running your tests from the gradle command line, or have a requirement to run tests that are not in your Test Suite, you can suppress tests or find an appropriate solution that works for you by reading the documentation on [AndroidJUnitRunner](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/test/runner/AndroidJUnitRunner).